# Function parameter type depends on another parameter

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to cover types cases when function `fireEvent` accept the function name what should be called at first param and on second function params.

```
  const eventsSchema = {
    onComplete: ({ id, name }: { id: number, name: string }): void => { 
      // do some things 
    },
    onStart: ({ name }: { name: string }): void => { 
      // do some things 
    },
    onCancel: ({ reason }: { reason: string }): void => { 
      // do some things 
    },
  }

  function fireEvent<K extends keyof typeof eventsSchema>(event: K, params: Parameters<typeof eventsSchema[K]>[0]) {
    return eventsSchema[event](params);
  }
```

as result works fine

```
  fireEvent('onComplete', { id, name }); // ok as expected
  fireEvent('onComplete', { name }); // error as expected
  fireEvent('onStart', { id }); // ok as expected
  fireEvent('onStart', { id, reason }); // error as expected
  fireEvent('onCancel', { reason }); // ok as expected
  fireEvent('onCancel', { name, id }); // error as expected
```

BUT I have an error inside fireEvent

[image]

How to cover this?

Comment: THis is because the safest way is to make `params` an intersection of all allowed props. THe only way is to use type assertion here. You can check my [article](https://catchts.com/react-props) for more explanation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this example:

```js
const eventsSchema = {
    onComplete: ({ id, name }: { id: number, name: string }): void => {
        // do some things 
    },
    onStart: ({ name }: { name: string }): void => {
        // do some things 
    },
    onCancel: ({ reason }: { reason: string }): void => {
        // do some things 
    },
}

function fireEvent<K extends keyof typeof eventsSchema>(event: K, params: Parameters<typeof eventsSchema[K]>[0]) {
    const args = params
    const fn = eventsSchema[event];
}
```

`fn` expects an intersection of all methods arguments, because it is the safest way to call this function. You don't know inside a function scope which argument was provided.

Also, TypeSCript is more efficient if you use pure functions. `fireEvent` is not pure, because it depends on `eventsSchema`.

SO, in your example it is a good idea to use currying:

```js
const eventsSchema = {
    onComplete: ({ id, name }: { id: number, name: string }): void => {
        // do some things 
    },
    onStart: ({ name }: { name: string }): void => {
        // do some things 
    },
    onCancel: ({ reason }: { reason: string }): void => {
        // do some things 
    },
}

type Schema = typeof eventsSchema

type Fn = (...args: any[]) => void
const withSchema = <
    S extends Record<string, Fn>
>(schema: S) =>
    <Name extends keyof S>(name: Name, ...params: Parameters<S[Name]>) => schema[name](...params)

const fireEvent = withSchema(eventsSchema)

fireEvent('onComplete', { id: 42, name: '' }) // ok
fireEvent('onComplete', { id: 42, name: 2 }) // expected error
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/w23k8N)

MOre information about this techniue you can find in my [blog](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments#second_level_inference)